# Attach PDF document to Email C# Windows Application - Email does not send out

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to attach PDF document to MailMessage Send method in Windows Form Application. I am using below code to attach document to email.

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"c:\Files\churchapplication.pdf"));
```

Email is not generated and no exception is raised either so i am unable to troubleshoot the problem. Same code works if I attach text file instead of pdf. So what could be the issue? Any ideas? PDF file size 291 KB. Is there some restrictions with attaching PDF documents in .NET?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try to debug with some local SMTP debugging server (like [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut))? If it works with .txt but not with .pdf, I'd suspect some server side problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this multi-step approach.

```
//First create FileContent
FileContentResult fileContent = File(fileName, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileContent.FileContents); 

// Create an in-memory System.IO.Stream
ContentType ct = new ContentType(fileContent.ContentType);

Attachment a = new Attachment(ms, ct);

sender.SendMail("email", "email", "subject", "Body", a);
```